# Elements with the same height and margin are displayed differently

Tags: html, css

I have three horizontal lines, that I want to have same height and same distance from each other.

Depending on height and margin, some lines are always smaller/larger. How can I make them the same size?

```css
div{
    margin:20px;
}

.line{
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    width: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span class="line"></span>
    <span class="line"></span>
    <span class="line"></span>
</div>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: `height`, `width` and `margin` do not seem to work on `display: inline;` elements. Try giving the `span`s a `display: block;`

Comment: Sorry, It was my copying mistake. I did gave `span`'s the `display: block;`. I updated my question.

Comment: @MantasLukosevicius What combination of `margin` and dimensions for the lines causes the mismatch? I cant seem to reproduce the image you included.

Comment: The snippet seems to work fine now. Are you sure there is no other styling in your project which is changing it? (considering you only posted the required portion of the code on SO). You can also do an *inspect element* on the individual element to see all the applied styles on it.

Comment: check your zoom level in your browser - some broswers dont hanle sub-pixel rendering well at zoom. The snippet as provides works well for me

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the height was distorted by the browser's zoom level and only in Chrome/Brave.

As @gavgrif pointed out in the comments some broswers dont handle sub-pixel rendering well at zoom.